# Delete duplicate rows in SAS

Tags: csv, sas, duplicates

I am trying to delete duplicate rows from a csv file using SAS but haven't been able to do so. My data looks like-

```
site1,variable1,20151126000000,22.8,140,1
site1,variable1,20151126010000,22.8,140,1
site1,variable2,20151126000000,22.8,140,1
site1,variable2,20151126000000,22.8,140,1
site2,variable1,20151126000000,22.8,140,1
site2,variable1,20151126010000,22.8,140,1
```

The 4th row is a duplicate of the 3rd one. This is just an example, I have more than a thousand records in the file. I tried doing this by creating subsets but didn't get the desired results. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you read the CSV file into SAS? If so, provide your code.  Do you have code to re-create the CSV file from a SAS dataset? If so provide that code too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use `nodupkey` for this, just reference your key, or you can use `_all_` -

```
proc sort data = file nodupkey;
by _all_;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this article you find different options to remove duplicate rows: https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings17/0188-2017.pdf

If all columns are sorted the easiest way is to use the option `noduprecs`:

```
proc sort data = file noduprecs;
by some_column;
run;
```

In contrast to the option `nodupkey` no matter which column or columns you state after the `by` it will always remove duplicate rows based on all columns.

Edit: Apparently, all columns have to be sorted (-> have a look at the comment below).

Comment: The NODUPRECS (original know as NODUPS) option is NOT guaranteed to remote all duplicate rows.  It only compares adjacent rows, so if the data is not sorted by all of the columns then duplicates can be separated by one or more non matching rows causeing them to not be detected.

Comment: @Tom: Thank you for the hint! I adjusted my answer.